# error of creating a stored procedure in netezza database from python by pypyodbc

Tags: python, database, stored-procedures, netezza, pypyodbc

I am working on python (pydev) in Eclipse on win7.

I need to access netezza SQL database from python (pypyodbc) to create a stored procedure.

I can create the stored procedure well from IBM Aginity workbench.

But, I got error of I do this from python.

```
  pypyodbc.Error: ('HY000', '[HY000] ERROR:  Creating procedure: permission denied.')
```

How to get the permission ?

thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You can get the permission by either way -

1) Make yourself as owner for the object (database, table) which will provide you all the permission (Including create/execute/alter function/procedure).

e.g. - Change owner for a table -

> `=> alter table <tbl_name> owner to <owner_name>;`

2) Request from admin to get necessary permission to create and execute procedure -

e.g. - Get "execute" (object privilege) for (database, table)

```
db.schema(admin/user with rights) => grant execute on <tbl_name/db_name> to <user>;
```

e.g. - Get "Create procedure" (admin privilege)

```
db.schema(admin/user with rights) =>  grant create procedure \
                                      in <[database_name.]schema_name | database_name.ALL | ALL.ALL> \
                                      to <user>;
```

Hope this will help.